# Epimorphisms in Kleisli categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

I [recently asked a question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455238/epimorphisms-of-relations) about characterizing epimorphisms in ${\bf Rel} = {\rm Kl}(P)$, where $P:\bf Set \to Set$ is the covariant powerset monad.

In my question I observed that a morphism $R : A \to B$ in ${\rm Kl}(P)$ is epi whenever $\delta^*R : \delta^*A \to B$ is epi in $\bf Set$, where the latter is the pullback of $R$ along the unit $\delta_B :B \to PB$ of $P$:

[image: pullback]

This amounts to say that $R$ is 'surjective on singletons'.

This observation actually works for any monad $(P, \delta, \mu)$ on any category $\cal C$, provided the necessary pullback exists. In fact consider the following commutative diagram:

[image]

The bottom strings of morphisms (there's two) express composition of $R:A \to B$ and $S,T:B \to C$ in ${\rm Kl}(P)$. Assume that indeed those two strings are equal, then by commutativity of the diagram the top two strings are also equal. Then if we assume $R$ is 'epi relative to the unit', meaning $\delta^* R$ is an epimorphism in $\cal C$, then we can conclude $S=T$. Hence we proved $RS = RT \implies S=T$, i.e. that $R$ is epi in ${\rm Kl}(P)$.

Now, for the case of relations, Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine proved (in his answer to the aforementioned question) this condition is actually necessary, so it completely characterizes epimorphisms in $\bf Rel$.
I suspect this doesn't hold in generality, since Peter's proof relied quite crucially on the self-duality of $\bf Rel$.

Can we fix it somehow?